# Getting an object from a parameter array using its name as index?

Tags: azure-pipelines

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#variables

According to Microsoft documentation there is no guarantee that a variable with value expression that depends on other variable with value expression will have the expected value, because the order of processing variables is not guarantee.

But What if the dependency is of a parameter and not another variable?

Assuming that the parameters are processed before variables, can I do the following?

```
variables:
  SelectedRepository: ${{ parameters.RepositoryList[variables['Build.Repository.Name'] }}
```

*RepositoryList* is a parameter with a complex object array.

I get the error **A mapping was not expected**, am I missing something or is just not possible?